# Subsonic 3 - Does is it support querying using the IEnumerable.Contains?

Tags: c#, subsonic, subsonic3

This fails with an error with the method "Contains" is not supported.

```
List<int> usedID= new List<int> { 1, 2, 3 };
var f = WebPageContent.Find(x => !usedID.Contains(x.PageID));
```

Seems odd so what's the alternative approach?

This doesn't work either:

```
var dd = from i in WebPageContent.All() 
         where !usedID.Contains(i.PageID) 
         select i;
```

This does but is it the recommended approach:

```
var table = new WebPageContentTable(_db.DataProvider);
var g = new SubSonic.Query.Select()
            .From(table)
            .Where(table.ID)
            .In(usedID)
            .Execute();
```

Answer (score 4):

Not knowing anything about Subsonic/Subsonic 3 I suggest that you use the [`Any`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.any.aspx) (or [`Contains`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.contains.aspx)) extension method and see if it's supported.

```
List<int> usedID= new List<int> { 1, 2, 3 };
var f = WebPageContent.Find(x => !usedID.Any( e => e == x.PageID));
```

Comment: If usedId is empty the Find falls over because of a null.

protected virtual Expression VisitUnary(UnaryExpression u)
        {
            Expression operand = this.Visit(u.Operand);
            //********** operand IS NULL HERE ********
            if (operand != u.Operand)
            {
                return Expression.MakeUnary(u.NodeType, operand, u.Type, u.Method);
            }
            return u;
        }

Comment: I also ran into this problem, and the answer above does work, but I believe that it is a problem with the SubSonic SQL translator, and not an error in your LINQ syntax.  Even Rob Conery, the writer of SubSonic says it should work.  See this reference: http://blog.wekeroad.com/blog/creating-in-queries-with-linq-to-sql/